Is there a limit to the number of REST clients in a Quarkus application?
I'm developing a Quarkus application and I'm wondering if there's a recommended limit to the number of REST clients I should use.
Specifically, I'm concerned about:

Resource management (memory, threads)
Connection pooling
Overall performance impact

Additionally, the REST clients in my application are not reactive.
Are there best practices or guidelines for managing multiple REST clients in Quarkus?

This is no practical limit, but the client does have some non negligible impact. Unless you are creating hundreds of them, I wouldn't worry about it

In which context are your rest clients used? Assuming you need them in a context of a worker thread spawned by an own rest endpoint this should have no big impact, since the client is shooed to the worker thread. Memory might become an issue, depending on the number of requests. But I don’t think there is a best practice. What you should consider: when having a huge amount of requests I’d recommend to switch to reactive …
